# Ubuntu upgrade and Drupal 6

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, drupal

Totally stuck with Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade and Drupal 6.

My server is really old and the Drupal version is also outdated, so I've decided to copy the existing instance on Linode to another instance to proceed with the Ubuntu upgrade.

The second instance is now upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04

But after upgrading my Drupal 6 site stopped working, it throws errors like:

```
Notice: Undefined index: path in /var/www/includes/database.mysqli.inc on line 69 
Warning: No database selected query: SELECT 1 FROM access WHERE type = 'host' AND LOWER('xx.xx.xx.xx') LIKE LOWER(mask) AND status = 0 LIMIT 0, 1 in /var/www/includes/database.mysqli.inc on line 134 
Warning: No database selected query: SELECT u.*, s.* FROM users u INNER JOIN sessions s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = '1m6gn6n6hjj2vbtcoirudfuuf5' in /var/www/includes/database.mysqli.inc on line 134 
Warning: No database selected query: SELECT data, created, headers, expire, serialized FROM cache WHERE cid = 'variables' in /var/www/includes/database.mysqli.inc on line 134"
```

**On my production Ubuntu 12.04:**

PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Apr  4 2014 01:30:04)

MySQL 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-log (Ubuntu)

nginx version: nginx/1.1.19

**On upgraded Ubuntu 14.04**

PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.29 (cli) (built: Apr 22 2019 18:33:52)

MySQL 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Nginx log:

```
2022/09/20 14:03:16 [error] 24885#0: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /var/www/includes/database.mysqli.inc on line 68
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: path in /var/www/includes/database.mysqli.inc on line 69
PHP message: PHP Warning:  No database selected
```

I could access the database from HeidiSQL with sites/default/settings.php credentials from

```
$db_url = 'mysqli://username:password@localhost/databasename';
```

Comment: Why stop there? Latest Ubuntu is 22.04

Comment: Look in /var/www/includes/database.mysqli.inc and see where the `host` variable has gone